# +- 5V differential ADC in the market?

Tags: adc

I want to integrate an analog signal with +- 5v differential output with my rasberry pi 4b. I have 3 inputs.

I am quite new to ADCs and drowning in information instead of finding a solution.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried at mouser.com and other vendor sites? They have filters to help you find what you need. You might also want to have a look at this video on the EEVBlog: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqlAq266aTs Do note that +/-5V diff. output isn't trivial and there will be a lot of "traps" for a beginner.

Comment: Do you need to measure (digitize) voltages that go negative? how far negative? would a microphone output (10 milliVolts from a dynamic microphone) be your plan?

Comment: I have a university project to monitor a cnc tool with the help of a vibration sensor. I am stuck in China with barely any documentation for the sensor available. The most I can make out is 18-28 V DC input voltage, +-5 Vp signal. That is all the info I have about the sensor

Comment: I would apply +24v to the sensor, connect an oscilloscope to the output, and tap it with my finger or otherwise simulate working conditions to see how the output changes and if it ever goes negative.

Comment: I am pretty sure it does go into negative. I looked it up again and it is a three axis and speed sensor. The output is x y and z coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pis do not come with integrated Analog-to-Digital Converters (ADCs).

You will have to buy an external board (HAT in the Raspberry Pi lingo) that provides that functionality when connected to your RPi 4b board. You will also have to make sure that this board accepts differential voltages in the voltage range you have. If the absolute value of any of the voltages is negative (relative to the board's ground), you may have a really hard time to find something that will work for you.

Places you can starting looking for the appropriate HAT for you:

[Pinout.xyz](https://pinout.xyz/boards)

[Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/396)

[Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/?q=hat)

*UPDATE*

Let me know if you’d like to build your own ADC circuit instead.

Comment: It seems like your answer boils down to "shop for something that meets your needs". That doesn't seem very helpful to me.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson - I take your point. The alternative for the OP would be to build his own ADC circuit. If that’s where he wants to go, I’d be more than happy to point him to the right direction.